# Looking for info regarding internal implementation of jQuery selector engine (sizzle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

I'm looking for information regarding what Sizzle (jQuery) does internally when you run a selector against it.  Ideally either someone that's done a write-up/blog post about how different browsers or handled, or a site that can de-compile a selector for various browsers.  Specifically, I have a team that is saying code I wrote is locking up IE7 on very large data-sets:

```
.find('.row:not(.row-0) .col-' + colN + ':not(.forbid-transfer)')
```

And that changing it to:

```
.find('.row:not(.row-0) .col-' + colN).filter(':not(.forbid-transfer)')
```

fixes the speed issue.

To me this is a complete ***wtf*** since I'd assume that those two are identical within the engine, but apparently they aren't.  Note that *everything* within the parent container is a div so changing this to `div.row... div.col....` shouldn't speed up anything.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd recommend `.not()` instead of `filter(":not()")`, if you find there's no difference in performance

Comment: *" I have a team that is saying code I wrote is locking up IE7 on very large data-sets"* Step 1: Replicate that yourself in isolation. I have to admit I'm having trouble believing it. If it weren't for the earlier `:not` in the selector, I'd believe it on some browsers, because Sizzle will defer to `querySelectorAll` if you don't use any of its special pseudo-classes. But IE7 doesn't have `querySelectorAll`, and you're using `:not` elsewhere, so...

Comment: The main difference is that in the first case, the browser will be doing double class name tests on more elements than in the second, because (I think) it works from right to left. Thus it's checking for both the ".col-n" class and the "forbid-transfer" class *before* it checks to see if the element has the right sort of "row" parent.  In the second case, it doesn't have to worry about "forbid-transfer" until the list of candidates has been culled.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - I'd love to replicate it, but I'm working with an obstinate team that won't give us access to their server :/  @Pointy - makes sense, but I don't see why it would make a significant difference in this case.  The first filter, `.row:not(.row-0)` only ever excludes ~10 `.col` divs (the number in one row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that

```
.find('.row:not(.row-0)').find('.col-' + colN).filter(':not(.forbid-transfer)')
```

would be even faster in IE7, perhaps not in a browser that supports "querySelectorAll()". Even with that, it depends on the particulars of the page.